# Modifying Vue files "HTML" but not working on my localhost

Tags: vue.js

I'm running a Laravel project, and I have some vue files which I need to change (for example, erasing some stuff), but the thing is I erase them from the vue file, but they are still appearing on the website. If I modify anything else, like a welcome.blade or whatsoever, it does work, but not with this vue files.

Only time I got it to work was stopping the project, running npm run dev, npm run watch --poll and starting the server again with php artisan serve, but when I tried doing it again, it didn't work.

I don't know if I am missing something obvious here. Please help my out :) and also, if I'm missing some information here please tell me so I can post it so someone can help me. Thanks!

This is my package.json that is on my root folder.

`{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
        "lodash": "^4.17.13",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
    }
}`

Comment: Could it be that your Laravel project caches or moves the Vue output to somewhere from where it serves it?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite get what you are saying, I'm somewhat of a newbie to Vue.

Comment: Try with `npm run production`. And reload the page with Ctrl + F5 since browser will reload the page ignoring the cache.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ I did it, I ran npm run production, it compiled but then like it ended, idk if that's normal. Then I ran php artisan serve but it did not work (the changes of the vue file). I also ran npm run production at the same time that I was running the server on anoter terminal window, but didn't work. I also tried opening on incognito mode. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure yet if it's a Vue problem or if it's a problem with how your Laravel handles your JavaScript files. If the Laravel project moves your files from the place where Vue builds them to somewhere else to serve them to clients then it might only move those files once during your `php artisan serve` command. Could you post your package.json from the Vue project?

Comment: @Jeffrey sure, just edited the main.

Comment: Do you have a `main.js` file where Vue is initialized? I would start there and add a `console.log()` message and see if it shows up in the browser. If it doesn't you know that it's probably not Vue that's the issue but something else. From there you could continue. If the message does show up you can see if you're working in the right file or if there's some other mistake somewhere. Hard to help you through the whole process though.

Comment: I mean, I'm 100% sure this is the correct file because a couple of hours ago I deleted something from the file and It got deleted on the website. Thing is, I couldn't do that again. I'm also 100% sure that is a really silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Well your file need to be compile so you need to run when editing `npm run watch` and you'll see live changement on reload and possibly some error discarding on the terminal you are running it from.

This is explicitly specify in the "tips" of Laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/frontend#writing-javascript) about Vue.

Comment: this is either not working, or i'm not getting it. I have my terminal running with the php artisan serve, I open another, get to my project, and then run `npm run watch` ? If that's what you meant, I'm not getting any updates :(